# Why is the return value of the variable declaration the previous statement's

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is the return value of the variable declaration the previous statement's ?

```
"some text"; var x = 10;
```

results in "some text" in console log.

Can anyone explain why does this happen. Where does this string actually gets stored, as it prints out the value irrespective of whatever input I give.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was tweeted by Paul Irish yesterday, and answered by Brendan Eich. (Except Paul's tweet correctly had `"omg"` instead of `"some text"`.)

Comment: You mean it prints "some text" surely

Comment: The code you've shown is insufficient to demonstrate the problem you describe; please include "*[mcve]*" code.

Comment: @Pointy Yes I know. I am not taking credit for the question. I wasn't able to understand the explanation that Brendan Eich provided. I am new to JS so wanted a detailed explaination.
Note: I changed the text to "some text" because i tried it myself

Comment: OK, well it would have been a good idea to fully explain that situation in your question here. You could have included the question as above but also the answer that Mr. Irish retweeted later, and then gone on to explain what it is that you didn't understand.

Comment: @Pointy I came across this tweet from my mobile and I am posting this question from my laptop. So wasn't able to post the tweet or retweet.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am aware of the fact that it answer's the question. I have already mentioned that I don't understand the explaination

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am at my workplace and my workplace has blocked all sorts of microblogging sites.

Comment: My posting the question here doesn't serve the purpose. We are talking something very unimportant. I do not even care whether my question is down voted more until and unless it answers my doubt.

Comment: @PratikBasak: Well, I gave you the link above, and there's an "edit" link on the question, which you can use to correct the issues above. But instead I suggest deleting the post (as it's attracted downvotes, perhaps IMHO a bit unfairly), then when you can access twitter, post it fresh with the link and the full text of Irish's question and Eich's answer, and ask if someone can explain Eich's explanation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder down voting my question doesn't answer my doubt. Atleast guys please if you could clear my doubts. I am a newbie to javascript,

Comment: @PratikBasak: What makes you think I downvoted the question? Or did anything other than *try to help*? (Not a mistake I'll make a second time.)

Comment: Stack doesn't show people who down vote. I guessed and it seems i guessed it wrong. Please just help me understand since you have access to twitter.

Comment: @PratikBasak answer posted :)

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. Going through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the snowbank of comments that piled up on this question: Paul Irish tweeted this yesterday:

> JavaScript question. Why is the return value of the variable declaration the previous statement's? #confused

followed by this sample code:

[image]

A bit later, he retweeted Brendan Eich's reply, which was that the string value represented the *statement completion value*.

The concept of statement completion values is a little weird because they don't really *do* anything in the domain of practical JavaScript programming. It's a construct that instructs the way the runtime should process a statement list.

In this case, the statement list (the list of statements typed on one line in the console) consists of the expression statement `"omg";` and the `var` declaration and initialization `var x = 4;`. The completion value of the first expression is the expression value, that being the string. The completion value of the *second* statement is empty, and the rules for constructing the completion value for the statement list are that the value should be the string; basically the last statement value that's not empty.

Now, again: this information is not particularly useful. It does explain how the `console` system works, which is nice to know I suppose. It's *important* stuff in terms of the language semantics of course, it's just not something that affects day-to-day programming tasks.

Comment: Gah, I misread [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-variable-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation) early on. Sure enough, even with an initializer, the statement completion value is Empty (if you follow enough links in the spec).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's a pretty ethereal topic; [here's one thread about a particular case](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/loop-unrolling-and-completion-values-in-es6). I'm sure it's super-interesting to people who carry the ES2015 spec around in their heads :)

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. Got what you meant. Similarly if I enter a number instead of a "string", it will behave similarly. Just typing an expression is considered a full statement was not known. Thanks for the info and the answer.